# Separability of a certain space of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $I$ be a separable, locally compact Hausdorff space, and let $V$ be a separable, locally convex, complete topological vector space. Consider the function space $C(I, V)$ with the compact-open topology.

Is $C(I,V)$ separable?

Comment: The tensor product $C(I) \otimes V$ should be dense in $C(I,V)$.

Comment: @Jochen, for a generic topological vector space, there are many types of tensor products (from the projective to the injective). Which are you referring to?

Comment: If you want to have equality $C(I,V)=C(I)\tilde{\otimes}V$ for the *completed* tensor product you need the *injective* tensor product (I am not sure which assumptions you need for $I$, it is often stated for compact $I$). However, If you just want separability you don't need a topology: If the algebraic tensor product (that is the span of functions of the form $x\mapsto f(x) v$ for $f\in C(I)$ and $v\in V$) is dense it would be enough to take dense subsets of such $f$ and $v$.